# Can I zoom in and out in macOS / Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, zoom

Is it possible to Zoom around in macOS? I mean *anywhere* in macOS, even in Finder? And by Zoom I mean being able to Zoom in and out whenever you want!

**Use Case**

Many times a day I change my screen’s resolution (in System Preferences/Display Preferences), but if I could zoom in and out no matter what app I was in, even in Finder, that would be perfect. I was thinking a keyboard shortcut like using ⌘+ and ⌘- in some apps to zoom in and out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this by using <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> for zooming in and <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> for zooming out.

If the above shortcuts don’t work:

1. Go to **Apple > System Preferences > Keyboard**
2. Select the Shortcuts tab
3. Click on Accessibility in the left pane
4. Make sure that the Zoom checkbox is ticked in the right pane

Answer (score 2):

You can zoom using Keyboard commands.
First you need to switch it on from System Prefs > Acessibility

[image]

& then you can change the specific key commands in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts

[image]