# How to utterly disable every and all zoom gestures on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: big-sur, trackpad, zoom, gesture

I have all Scroll & Zoom options unchecked in the Trackpad preference pane of my Macbook Pro running macOS Big Sur 11.6. Nonetheless, every now and then as I am using a word processor, or spreadsheet, etc. I will fat-finger some combination of keys and Trackpad and the screen will **freak out** with zooming way in or out.

I am done with this. How can I utterly disable any and all zoom gestures on my system?

I am quite happy to get down on the command line.

Comment: Have you checked Accessibility & Keyboard prefs? See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327660/can-i-zoom-in-and-out-in-macos-finder/327662#327662 [Mojave, Big Sur is slightly different]

Comment: @Tetsujin That is a really great comment, thank you! As it so happens all that stuff is unchecked, although I was not aware of it.